# New to programming, trying to solve this Isogram kata (using .match javascript)

Tags: javascript

I started to learn programming about a month ago. and just started some kata's on codewars for practice.

currently on this one.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/isograms/javascript

An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is an isogram. Ignore letter case.

My Plan
 1. split the string up into an array (as im writing this i realize this step might not be necessary...)
 2. use .match & length to check for repeating letters (if length > 1)

Below is my rough code, but I am unable to get it doing what I want.
I am only able to put a predefined letter within the .match method, in my code below I put /a/ just as a placeholder, it will correctly output that a occurs 5x and 1x respectively in the two examples.

What I want it do it is use strArray[i] with .match(), and have the loop test each letter within strArray using .match.  If the length of any of them are over 1, then function will return false

I know there are probably better ways to solve this etc, (ive seen solutions on codewars. that are only 1-2 lines..)  Ive looked at them, but they seem way to complicated, At the moment I am trying to solve using a method I understand.

```
function isIsogram(str) {
  let strArray = str.split('')
  console.log(strArray)

  for(let i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let x = strArray[i]
    let checkRepeat = str.match(/a/gi).length

    console.log(checkRepeat)
  }

  return
}
console.log(isIsogram("aaabbaac")) //false
console.log(isIsogram("abcde"))    //true
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use `.match` to check for repeating letters, there's no need for any other code, since this can be achieved with a single regular expression. Capture a character, then eventually match that same character again using a backreference. If that same character is found, then it's not an isogram, else it is an isogram:

```
const isIsogram = str => !str.match(/(.).*\1/i);
```

The pattern `(.).*\1` means:

- `(.)` - Match any character, and put it into a capture group
- `.*` - Match zero or more characters
- `\1` - Followed by the same character of the earlier capture group

Plus the case-insensitive flag, `i`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But Im not going to lie, I have no idea how what you wrote works.

Ive been learning javascript for about a month, and have not seen anything like what you wrote, it just looks like a bunch of random dots, brackets etc.

Do you not need a loop to check all the letters? 

I've probably done a dozen katas on codewars, and every time I write 'long' code thats like 10-20 lines.  only to submit and see code like yours where people do it in just a couple.

I feel like i am missing something, Whatever im learning takes 10x more code to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's the power of regular expressions - they provide a very concise way to match complicated patterns in strings. You're already using a regular expression with your `/a/gi`, you just need to expand it to the logic you need.